# Mongoose: custom type augmenting schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to use the power of mongoose custom types, but there's one issue i cannot find a workaround for. Basically we need to persist time zone for date using the following schema

```
{
   date: {type: Date}, //UTC date for ease of use
   zone: {type: String} //Initial timezone that allows to restore local date
}
```

I've sketched up custom type LocalDate with `cast` function that returns `{date: , zone: }` object for standard date string alike `2014-10-24T14:00:00+0500` (Not sure if this is valid, so any suggestions are most welcome).
The problem is that given the following code

```
//Schema is extended with LocalDate already
var test = new Schema({
  birthday: {type: Schema.Types.LocalDate}
});

var doc = new test({birthday: '2014-10-24T14:00:00+0500'});
doc.save(function(err){
  //err is null here. 
});
```

Document inserted to the DB and has _id. But birthday path is not saved at all.

It looks like `cast` is never called though. Here's how it's defined

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  var Types = mongoose.Types;
  var SchemaType = mongoose.SchemaType;
  function LocalDate(){
     SchemaType.call(this, key, options);
  }
  LocalDate.prototype.__proto__ = SchemaType.prototype;

  //Here comes checkRequired, $conditionalHandlers etc. which seem to be irrelevant here

   LocalDate.prototype.cast = function(val, scope, init){
     console.log('casting LocalDate'); //Never logged
     if (null === val || '' === val) return null;

     if (_.isObject(val)){ 
      return fromObject(val);
     }
     throw new SchemaType.CastError('LocalDate', val);
   };

     Schema.Types.LocalDate = LocalDate;
     Types.LocalDate = LocalDate;
     return LocalDate;
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?